# how to check time slots colliding or not in laravel where time are stored as string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, time

I am working on a slot I want to check if the given time is colliding with any other entries of my DB.

Here is my sample DB structure data, both time slots stored as string so the query is not responding as expected.

| time_slot_starts (varchar) | time_slot_ends (varchar) | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9.00 am | 9.30 am | Sunday |
| 9.30 am | 11.30 am | Sunday |

```php
Meetings::where(function ($query) use ($slot_start, $slot_end) {
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($slot_start, $slot_end) {
        $query->where('time_slot_starts', '<=', $slot_start)
            ->where('time_slot_ends', '>', $slot_start);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($slot_start, $slot_end) {
        $query->where('time_slot_starts', '<', $slot_end)
            ->where('time_slot_ends', '>=', $slot_end);
    });
})
->count();
```

This is the query I used but it always returns `0`.

Comment: You must convert string to time (use STR_TO_DATE function in MySQL or according PHP function) then compare. Overlapping condition is `start1<end2 and start2<end1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the value structure of storing time slots to 24 hrs format and stored as H:i:s